# Generate a unique 8-digit number from the _id field (MongoDB/Javasccript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, algorithm

I need to generate a unique 8-digit number for each user. To do this, I can make a random number and check if it has been used before. But I do not think this is a good idea. Because with the increase in the number of users, the number of requests to the database also increases.
Since I'm using the MongoDB database, it might be an good idea to make this unique number from _id.

for example:

```
6008195dae2ad926a15a4682
```

Become a unique number like this:

```
83921037
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this cannot be possible because there are more than 10^8 possible values for `_id`.

But you can use `_id` to generate hash-value in the range 0...99999999 and than check if the number is not yet used. If it is already in use (=collision) you need to handle this.